# Position in a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to divide an element by his position in a collection.
I know this query doesn't work but it's the idea:

```
START a=node(0)
MATCH path=a-[rel*1..3]->b
With b,path, extract(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(path):r.p1) AS Collection
Return b, reduce(sum = 0, i in RANGE(1,LENGTH(Collection)): sum + (Collection[i]/i)) as result
```

It is possible to access a specific element in a collection ?
Is there a way to do that kind of things in Cypher ?

Comment: It is possible in the version of 2.0-M05 to access an element in a collection by index. But I don't know how to construct a range with a variable as the upperbound.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Definitely, i'm going to work now with the version 2.0. I tried to return a specific element in a collection like this : "collection[i]" and it works. And what I wanted to do with the reduce function works too.

Comment: Great! So how did you construct the index range for the collection. The range with a variable upperbound doesn't seem to work, does it?

Comment: It works well. I just had to correct my query like this : "REDUCE(sum = 0, i IN RANGE(0,LENGTH(Collection)-1)| sum +(Collection[i]/(i+1))) as result" in order not to have this error : "OutOfBoundsException : Passed the end of the collection Collection".

Comment: It indeed works. Thanks!